# How to access the internal hard disk with full permissions?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-disk, permission, data-transfer

My Mac does not start anymore. The hard disk is stranded :-( Macs and gravity are not good friends.

When starting on a backup disk, I manage to see some contents of the internal disk *Macintosh HD*, but strangely some permissions prevent me to see everything. For example, in *Users*, I cannot explore all the home folders.

[Edit]

1. **How can I access the internal hard disk with full permissions ?**
2. **Why don't I see everything on the internal disk when it is not the boot disk ?**

I want to salvage the data. To do this, I intend to do copies with the Finder.

Thank you for your insight on this delicate matter.

The internal disk, and the backup disk, have Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: How familiar are you with the command line interface (Terminal)? Have you tried enabling and using the root user?

Comment: @bernk - I have not enabled the root user.

Comment: @bernk - What is preventing me from seeing everything on the internal disk *Macintosh HD* ? For the Mac, it is just a plugged disk, it is not the boot disk.

Comment: As you've said yourself, permissions. Using a regular admin user are you able to change the permissions of one of those folders to give yourself access? Select the folder and cmd-i to Get Info, at the bottom you'll see the permissions. You can click on the lock to change them, but this'll require an admin account.

Answer (score 3):

One way to recover files from a "broken disk" without buying software, is to use the Target Disk mode.

You will need a second mac to do that, to which you would transfer the files.

Comment: You are welcome, hope it works and to have saved you some money.